# Is it ok to use same BasicDataSource, Connection, Statement and ResultSet Object in multiple class methods.?

Tags: java, maven, debugging, garbage-collection, apache-commons-dbcp

I have below code which uses static objects of BasicDataSource, Sql Connection, Statement and ResultSet. The code below is working fine, but i just want to know about the safety of using these kinds of coding practices. or how can i optimize the below code so that it can become more stable and can reliable.

```
public class Testing {
     static BasicDataSource bds = DBConnection.getInstance().getBds();
     static Connection con = null;
     static PreparedStatement stmt = null;
     static ResultSet rs = null;

    private void show() {
        try {
            con = bds.getConnection();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("firstname") + " " + rs.getString("lastname"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private void display() {
        try {
            con = bds.getConnection();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM agent_cities");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("city_name"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private void add() {
        try {
            con = bds.getConnection();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE users SET firstname = 'shsh' WHERE id = 2");
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("updated successfully");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testing t = new Testing();
        t.show();
        t.display();
        t.add();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Do share your cases on which you can break above code and question about its safety.

**Update :** 
Updating only to ensure that no one should use static fields as i have used in above program because above program contains bug when deployed on dev server.

After using above code on large systems i found the bug. one month ago i had no problem with the above code and it was working fine but today i found the bug.

**Bug:**

After hitting my APIs 6-7 times it stopped giving response at 8th hit. i really don't know why and have no idea about loop holes present in program. 
But now as i have accepted the answer i changed my source code and started using try-with resources in my code and removed static fields.

But i am still curious to know about the bug that i found in the above code.
that doesn't gives response and hangs after 7-8 API hits.
Please share your thoughts on this. i'm using apache tomcat 8.5.32 server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of an application, you really should not be using fields for connections, statements and result sets (and static fields are even a bigger smell).

Comment: Then what are better alternatives.

Comment: Local variables of course.

Comment: and waht's the reason for that

Comment: It prevents connection from living too long, it prevents inadvertent sharing of connections between multiple threads, and it prevents other types of resource leaks.

Comment: don't you think that declaring local variables every time in separate methods is time consuming for large systems which i have.

Comment: As I said in my initial comment: it depends, but generally, having them static is a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use **try-with-resources**. This automatically closes Connection, Statement and ResultSet, even when an exception was raised, or on an inner return.

```
    String sql = "UPDATE users SET firstname = ? WHERE id = ?";
    try (Connection con = bds.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement()) {
        stmt.setString(1, "shsh");
        stmt.setLong(2, 2);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("updated successfully");
    }

    String sql = "SELECT city_name FROM agent_cities";
    try (Connection con = bds.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement()) {
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("city_name"));
            }
        }
    }
```

This is better for garbage collection. Prevents unnice rs2, rs3. Allows multi-user concurrency, like in a server application. Calls that query themselves.
And `static` is even more in the style of global variables.

Comment: This is not about garbage collection but *resource cleanup* whereas “resource” means any resource *not* managed by Java’s garbage collector. The memory of these objects in the Java heap is only a minor issue.

Comment: @Holger true, thanks. In fact I am a bit lost of finding the correct words here. An old style C / Fortran programmer would use global variables as proposed.

Comment: The wording is tricky, as with other programming languages, anything that needs allocation and deallocation is a “resource”, which includes explicitly managed memory. The mind job of a Java programmer is to exclude the managed heap memory from the set of resources, while considering “resource” as something that still needs explicit closing (considering using `try(…)` as explicit management) and should be closed as early as possible. Then, it gets easier to understand the futility of the old idea of closing resources in a finalizer, as the garbage collector *only* cares for heap memory.

Comment: Thanks. from now i will use above  try-with-resources block.

Comment: @JoopEggen please look at the Update part in question and share your opinion about it

Comment: It could be a kind of resource leakage (Holger's comment), too many connections, statements per connection held open. But that is pure speculation. When a field is overwritten, the old object is not closed etcetera. A **connection pool**? Max connections? Database engines have debug switches.

Answer (score 1):

It is more or less ok if we are talking about such a small program. 
But there is no need to keep con, stmt and rs as a static variables, they can be declared inside a method. Also, you need to rewrite try catch finally blocks and close resources properly:

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
  // your code
} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
  try { if (stmt != null) stmt.close(); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
  try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

As a next step you can check [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construction to clean up this code.

Comment: Yeah. but i have much large program where i can't create new objects for each method signature so what is your solution for very large program containing many method signatures.

Comment: It depends on the tech stack. If you have java without spring/hibernate, then you need a single data source (which you already have `static BasicDataSource bds = DBConnection.getInstance().getBds();`) and close resources properly.

Comment: yup i am not using spring/hibernate. i am using Java Servlets and Maven as a build tool with Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You should use try-with-resources to avoid any kind of connection leaks.

The following example reads the first line from a file. It uses an instance of BufferedReader to read data from the file. BufferedReader is a resource that must be closed after the program is finished with it:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br =
                   new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```